# Set cropped background image to custom ListView item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a ListView with custom views and I have a custom ArrayAdapter for it too. I want to set background image for my custom view. I know it's possible to do it via **android:background**, but when I do it whole image (which is 1500x1500) gets set for my ListView item. I want the image be cropped for the item. I mean, if ListView item is 300x80 I want a 300x80 part of my background image get shown, not whole image scaled.

If it is possible via XML I prefer it but I can also do it programmatically. So, how can I set cropped backgournd for my custom ListView item?

P.S. The reason I chose this way is if I choose a small bitmap, the bitmap will look bad in big screen devices and if I choose big image, the image will be scaled and I don't want it.

Comment: `scaleType` attribute in xml, `center_crop`, doc and possibilities here developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html . you should create diffrent sizes using naming folders like `drawables-xhdpi` and other, `-large` and `-xlarge` as well

Comment: Actually I set centerCrop but image was still big for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to use [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) `centerCrop`

or crop the bitmap manually.

```
int startX = (bitmap.getWidth() > imageView.getWidth()) ? (bitmap.getWidth() - imageView.getWidth()) / 2 : 0;
int startY = (bitmap.getHeight() > imageView.getHeight()) ? (bitmap.getHeight() - imageView.getHeight()) / 2 : 0;

bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,                  
    startX,        
    startY, 
    (bitmap.getWidth() > imageView.getWidth())  ? imageView.getWidth() : bitmap.getWidth(), 
    (bitmap.getHeight() > imageView.getHeight()) ? imageView.getHeight() : bitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Well, how should I set to to ListView item's background? There is setBackground function for it but it expects a drawable from resource not Bitmap instance. How should I set it in getView function of custom ArrayAdapter?

Comment: use BitmapDrawable.

Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);